# Do something when audio stops

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Im wondering of how to make my app aware of when the audio stops. I have a 30 minute audio recorded thats triggered when you hit the play button. The play button is then changed to a pause button. I would like for the pause button to switch back to a play button when the audio is complete. I am using AVAudioPlayer. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please tag this as an iOS question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AVAudioPlayerDelegate contains a method called `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:`. You could override that method and put your play/pause button login in there.

Something like this:

**In .h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@end
```

**In .m**

```
@implementation ViewController{
    AVAudioPlayer *_player;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _player.delegate = self;
}  

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    //show play button
}

@end
```

More info on AVAudioPlayerDelegate [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVAudioPlayerDelegate)